# Python difflib.ndiff(i,j) differs from difflib.ndiff(j,i) by a huge margin

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I have two string i and j as follows:

`i = a party may disclose confidential information to the extent such confidential information is required to be disclosed by law, by any governmental or other regulatory authority or by a court or other authority of competent jurisdiction, provided that, to the extent it is legally permitted to do so, it gives the other party as much notice of such disclosure as possible and, where notice of disclosure is not prohibited and is given in accordance with this 10.4, it takes into account the reasonable requests of the other party in relation to the content of such disclosure.`

`j = 3) a party may disclose confidential information to the extent such confidential information is required to be disclosed by law, by any governmental or other regulatory authority or by a court or other authority of competent jurisdiction, provided that, to the extent it is legally permitted to do so, it gives the other party as much notice of such disclosure as possible and, where notice of disclosure is not prohibited and is given in accordance with this, it takes into account the reasonable requests of the other party in relation to the content of such disclosure.`

The output of `list(difflib.ndiff(j,i))` is

`['- 3', '- )', '-  ', '  a', '   ', '  p', '  a', '  r', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  m', '  a', '  y', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  e', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  n', '  f', '  i', '  d', '  e', '  n', '  t', '  i', '  a', '  l', '   ', '  i', '  n', '  f', '  o', '  r', '  m', '  a', '  t', '  i', '  o', '  n', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  e', '  x', '  t', '  e', '  n', '  t', '   ', '  s', '  u', '  c', '  h', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  n', '  f', '  i', '  d', '  e', '  n', '  t', '  i', '  a', '  l', '   ', '  i', '  n', '  f', '  o', '  r', '  m', '  a', '  t', '  i', '  o', '  n', '   ', '  i', '  s', '   ', '  r', '  e', '  q', '  u', '  i', '  r', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  b', '  e', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  b', '  y', '   ', '  l', '  a', '  w', '  ,', '   ', '  b', '  y', '   ', '  a', '  n', '  y', '   ', '  g', '  o', '  v', '  e', '  r', '  n', '  m', '  e', '  n', '  t', '  a', '  l', '   ', '  o', '  r', '   ', '  o', '  t', '  h', '  e', '  r', '   ', '  r', '  e', '  g', '  u', '  l', '  a', '  t', '  o', '  r', '  y', '   ', '  a', '  u', '  t', '  h', '  o', '  r', '  i', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  o', '  r', '   ', '  b', '  y', '   ', '  a', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  u', '  r', '  t', '   ', '  o', '  r', '   ', '  o', '  t', '  h', '  e', '  r', '   ', '  a', '  u', '  t', '  h', '  o', '  r', '  i', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  o', '  f', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  m', '  p', '  e', '  t', '  e', '  n', '  t', '   ', '  j', '  u', '  r', '  i', '  s', '  d', '  i', '  c', '  t', '  i', '  o', '  n', '  ,', '   ', '  p', '  r', '  o', '  v', '  i', '  d', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  a', '  t', '  ,', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  e', '  x', '  t', '  e', '  n', '  t', '   ', '  i', '  t', '   ', '  i', '  s', '   ', '  l', '  e', '  g', '  a', '  l', '  l', '  y', '   ', '  p', '  e', '  r', '  m', '  i', '  t', '  t', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  d', '  o', '   ', '  s', '  o', '  ,', '   ', '  i', '  t', '   ', '  g', '  i', '  v', '  e', '  s', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  o', '  t', '  h', '  e', '  r', '   ', '  p', '  a', '  r', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  a', '  s', '   ', '  m', '  u', '  c', '  h', '   ', '  n', '  o', '  t', '  i', '  c', '  e', '   ', '  o', '  f', '   ', '  s', '  u', '  c', '  h', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  u', '  r', '  e', '   ', '  a', '  s', '   ', '  p', '  o', '  s', '  s', '  i', '  b', '  l', '  e', '   ', '  a', '  n', '  d', '  ,', '   ', '  w', '  h', '  e', '  r', '  e', '   ', '  n', '  o', '  t', '  i', '  c', '  e', '   ', '  o', '  f', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  u', '  r', '  e', '   ', '  i', '  s', '   ', '  n', '  o', '  t', '   ', '  p', '  r', '  o', '  h', '  i', '  b', '  i', '  t', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  a', '  n', '  d', '   ', '  i', '  s', '   ', '  g', '  i', '  v', '  e', '  n', '   ', '  i', '  n', '   ', '  a', '  c', '  c', '  o', '  r', '  d', '  a', '  n', '  c', '  e', '   ', '  w', '  i', '  t', '  h', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  i', '  s', '+  ', '+ 1', '+ 0', '+ .', '+ 4', '  ,', '   ', '  i', '  t', '   ', '  t', '  a', '  k', '  e', '  s', '   ', '  i', '  n', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  a', '  c', '  c', '  o', '  u', '  n', '  t', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  r', '  e', '  a', '  s', '  o', '  n', '  a', '  b', '  l', '  e', '   ', '  r', '  e', '  q', '  u', '  e', '  s', '  t', '  s', '   ', '  o', '  f', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  o', '  t', '  h', '  e', '  r', '   ', '  p', '  a', '  r', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  i', '  n', '   ', '  r', '  e', '  l', '  a', '  t', '  i', '  o', '  n', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  n', '  t', '  e', '  n', '  t', '   ', '  o', '  f', '   ', '  s', '  u', '  c', '  h', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  u', '  r', '  e', '  .']`

there are only 8 differing characters, whereas the output of `list(difflib.ndiff(j,i))` is

`['+ 3', '+ )', '+  ', '  a', '   ', '  p', '  a', '  r', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  m', '  a', '  y', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  e', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  n', '  f', '  i', '  d', '  e', '  n', '  t', '  i', '  a', '  l', '   ', '  i', '  n', '  f', '  o', '  r', '  m', '  a', '  t', '  i', '  o', '  n', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  e', '  x', '  t', '  e', '  n', '  t', '   ', '  s', '  u', '  c', '  h', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  n', '  f', '  i', '  d', '  e', '  n', '  t', '  i', '  a', '  l', '   ', '  i', '  n', '  f', '  o', '  r', '  m', '  a', '  t', '  i', '  o', '  n', '   ', '  i', '  s', '   ', '  r', '  e', '  q', '  u', '  i', '  r', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  b', '  e', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  b', '  y', '   ', '  l', '  a', '  w', '  ,', '   ', '  b', '  y', '   ', '  a', '  n', '  y', '   ', '  g', '  o', '  v', '  e', '  r', '  n', '  m', '  e', '  n', '  t', '  a', '  l', '   ', '  o', '  r', '   ', '  o', '  t', '  h', '  e', '  r', '   ', '  r', '  e', '  g', '  u', '  l', '  a', '  t', '  o', '  r', '  y', '   ', '  a', '  u', '  t', '  h', '  o', '  r', '  i', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  o', '  r', '   ', '  b', '  y', '   ', '  a', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  u', '  r', '  t', '   ', '  o', '  r', '   ', '  o', '  t', '  h', '  e', '  r', '   ', '  a', '  u', '  t', '  h', '  o', '  r', '  i', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  o', '  f', '   ', '  c', '  o', '  m', '  p', '  e', '  t', '  e', '  n', '  t', '   ', '  j', '  u', '  r', '  i', '  s', '  d', '  i', '  c', '  t', '  i', '  o', '  n', '  ,', '   ', '  p', '  r', '  o', '  v', '  i', '  d', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  a', '  t', '  ,', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  e', '  x', '  t', '  e', '  n', '  t', '   ', '  i', '  t', '   ', '  i', '  s', '   ', '  l', '  e', '  g', '  a', '  l', '  l', '  y', '   ', '  p', '  e', '  r', '  m', '  i', '  t', '  t', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  t', '  o', '   ', '  d', '  o', '   ', '  s', '  o', '  ,', '   ', '  i', '  t', '   ', '  g', '  i', '  v', '  e', '  s', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  e', '   ', '  o', '  t', '  h', '  e', '  r', '   ', '  p', '  a', '  r', '  t', '  y', '   ', '  a', '  s', '   ', '  m', '  u', '  c', '  h', '   ', '  n', '  o', '  t', '  i', '  c', '  e', '   ', '  o', '  f', '   ', '  s', '  u', '  c', '  h', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  u', '  r', '  e', '   ', '  a', '  s', '   ', '  p', '  o', '  s', '  s', '  i', '  b', '  l', '  e', '   ', '  a', '  n', '  d', '  ,', '   ', '  w', '  h', '  e', '  r', '  e', '   ', '  n', '  o', '  t', '  i', '  c', '  e', '   ', '  o', '  f', '   ', '  d', '  i', '  s', '  c', '  l', '  o', '  s', '  u', '  r', '  e', '   ', '  i', '  s', '   ', '  n', '  o', '  t', '   ', '  p', '  r', '  o', '  h', '  i', '  b', '  i', '  t', '  e', '  d', '   ', '  a', '  n', '  d', '   ', '  i', '  s', '   ', '  g', '  i', '  v', '  e', '  n', '   ', '  i', '  n', '   ', '  a', '  c', '  c', '  o', '  r', '  d', '  a', '  n', '  c', '  e', '   ', '  w', '  i', '  t', '  h', '   ', '  t', '  h', '  i', '  s', '+ ,', '   ', '- 1', '- 0', '+ i', '+ t', '+  ', '+ t', '+ a', '+ k', '+ e', '+ s', '+  ', '+ i', '+ n', '+ t', '+ o', '+  ', '+ a', '+ c', '+ c', '+ o', '+ u', '+ n', '+ t', '+  ', '+ t', '+ h', '+ e', '+  ', '+ r', '+ e', '+ a', '+ s', '+ o', '+ n', '+ a', '+ b', '+ l', '+ e', '+  ', '+ r', '+ e', '+ q', '+ u', '+ e', '+ s', '+ t', '+ s', '+  ', '+ o', '+ f', '+  ', '+ t', '+ h', '+ e', '+  ', '+ o', '+ t', '+ h', '+ e', '+ r', '+  ', '+ p', '+ a', '+ r', '+ t', '+ y', '+  ', '+ i', '+ n', '+  ', '+ r', '+ e', '+ l', '+ a', '+ t', '+ i', '+ o', '+ n', '+  ', '+ t', '+ o', '+  ', '+ t', '+ h', '+ e', '+  ', '+ c', '+ o', '+ n', '+ t', '+ e', '+ n', '+ t', '+  ', '+ o', '+ f', '+  ', '+ s', '+ u', '+ c', '+ h', '+  ', '+ d', '+ i', '+ s', '+ c', '+ l', '+ o', '+ s', '+ u', '+ r', '+ e', '  .', '- 4', '- ,', '-  ', '- i', '- t', '-  ', '- t', '- a', '- k', '- e', '- s', '-  ', '- i', '- n', '- t', '- o', '-  ', '- a', '- c', '- c', '- o', '- u', '- n', '- t', '-  ', '- t', '- h', '- e', '-  ', '- r', '- e', '- a', '- s', '- o', '- n', '- a', '- b', '- l', '- e', '-  ', '- r', '- e', '- q', '- u', '- e', '- s', '- t', '- s', '-  ', '- o', '- f', '-  ', '- t', '- h', '- e', '-  ', '- o', '- t', '- h', '- e', '- r', '-  ', '- p', '- a', '- r', '- t', '- y', '-  ', '- i', '- n', '-  ', '- r', '- e', '- l', '- a', '- t', '- i', '- o', '- n', '-  ', '- t', '- o', '-  ', '- t', '- h', '- e', '-  ', '- c', '- o', '- n', '- t', '- e', '- n', '- t', '-  ', '- o', '- f', '-  ', '- s', '- u', '- c', '- h', '-  ', '- d', '- i', '- s', '- c', '- l', '- o', '- s', '- u', '- r', '- e', '- .']`

there are 230 differing characters, why is this happening?